# How to fix "data is required to be 'static" using tokio::spawn?

Tags: rust, lifetime, rust-tokio

I'm trying to listen to multiple TCP streams via tokio but I get an error:

```
use rybw_config::ListenerConfig;
use tokio::prelude::*;
use tokio::task::JoinHandle;
pub mod tcp;
use tcp::TCPListener;

pub struct Listener {
    config: ListenerConfig,
    tcp: Vec<tcp::TCPListener>,
}

impl Listener {
    pub fn new(config: ListenerConfig) -> Listener {
        let tcp: Vec<TCPListener> = config
            .tcp
            .clone()
            .unwrap()
            .iter()
            .map(|x| TCPListener::new((*x).clone()))
            .collect();

        Listener {
            tcp: tcp,
            config: config.clone(),
        }
    }

    pub async fn run(&self) {
        let handles: Vec<JoinHandle<()>> = self.tcp.iter().map(|i| {
            tokio::spawn(async {
                i.run().await
            })
        }).collect();
        futures::future::join_all(handles);
    }
```

```
error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime
  --> rybw-listener/src/lib.rs:28:22
   |
28 |     pub async fn run(&self) {
   |                      ^^^^^
   |                      |
   |                      data with this lifetime...
   |                      ...is captured here...
29 |         let handles: Vec<JoinHandle<()>> = self.tcp.iter().map(|i| {
30 |             tokio::spawn(async {
   |             ------------ ...and required to be `'static` by this
```

Answer (score 3):

Solved by myself.

rust closure captures the struct, not by individual fields. So we wrapper the TCPListener with std::sync::Arc and  cloning it then used in spawn async {}

Comment: I'm running with the same problem and I couldn't fix it, could you please explain more your solution ?

Comment: The solution with `Arc` is correct, but the reason isn't quite right. It is not capturing the whole struct, each task is only capturing each individual element, but those elements are *references* to the struct.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `i` in your example is `&tcp::TCPListener` where the reference is still tied to `self`. However, `tokio::spawn` requires the spawned task to be `'static` meaning it can't keep references to local variables.

The solution is to `move` owned values into the task. Common ways to do this are:

- Use `Clone` to create a copy of the data needed by the task.

  ```
  let handles: Vec<_> = self.tcp.iter().map(|listener| {
      let listener = listener.clone();
                          // ^^^^^^^^ create a copy
      tokio::spawn(async move {
                      // ^^^^ and move it into the async block
          listener.run().await
      })
  }).collect();
  ```
- Use shared ownership via `Arc` and `Clone` the handle needed by the task.

  ```
  use std::sync::Arc;

  struct Listener {
      config: ListenerConfig,
      tcp: Vec<Arc<tcp::TCPListener>>,
            // ^^^ allow shared ownership
  }
  ```

  ```
  let handles: Vec<_> = self.tcp.iter().map(|listener| {
      let listener = Arc::clone(listener);
                  // ^^^^^^^^^^ create a new handle to the same data
      tokio::spawn(async move {
                      // ^^^^ and move it into the async block
          listener.run().await
      })
  }).collect();
  ```
- Provide ownership directly to the task. This won't really be an option in your example since `&self` is an immutable reference. But if you had an owned `self` or mutable reference and didn't need to keep your listeners after spawning tasks for them, you could use something like `.into_iter()` or `.drain()` on `Vec` to *consume* the listeners so their type is `tcp::TCPListener` (not a reference) and can easily be `move`-d into the task.